# Array list error second array replace the first array

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem.

```
Dim Maxis As String
        'Dim MaxisExtra As String
        Dim b As New ArrayList
        Dim WS As New WebService1.Service1
        Dim cnt As String
        Dim MRWS As New MobileReload_WS.MobileReload_WS
        cnt = WS.StockCountTelco(1, Session("Maxis"))
        If CInt(cnt) >= CInt(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text) Then
            Dim sLock As String
            sLock = MRWS.LockAStock(1, 1, "Online", Session("Maxis"), DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
            Session("sLock") = sLock

            If sLock = "" Then
                PopupMsgBox("Unable to allocate Stock")
            Else
                Maxis = "Maxis" & ";" & Session("Maxis") & ";" & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text & ";" & Session("Cost")
                'If MaxisExtra = "" Then
                '    b.Add(Maxis)
                '    Elseif
                '    MaxisExtra = MaxisExtra + Maxis
                '    b.Add(MaxisExtra)
                'End If                
            End If
        Else
            PopupMsgBox("Not enough stock")
        End If
        b.Add(Maxis)
        Session("Transaction") = b
    End Sub
```

The first time i enter the string into the arraylist it is okay. But when the user press the button add again the second time, it replace the first string. Can anyone help me how to save the string into the second slot based on my coding?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the `b` `ArrayList`, then you're creating a new one each time and storing the new `ArrayList` in `Session("Transaction")`

Maybe you mean something like this instead...

```
Dim b as ArrayList = Session("Transaction")
If b Is Nothing Then
  b = new ArrayList
End If
...
Session("Transaction") = b
```

Although it's difficult to say exactly, because your code is very messy and not clear

Answer (score 0):

You put the array list in a session variable, but you never read it back. You create a new array list each time, so it will always be empty and replace the previous one.

Get the array list from the session variable if there is one:

```
Dim b As ArrayList = Session("Transaction")
If b Is Nothing Then b = New ArrayList
```